# ¿Por qué se nombra un directorio 'src' en proyectos, librerías, etc?

Tags: librería, código-fuente

Estaba analizando unas librerías y me surgió la duda. Es habitual que contengan un directorio "src", supongo que proviene de "source", pero no estoy seguro de que sea así y si lo es el porque de la forma abreviada... Tampoco se usa siempre y no se si es común encontrarlo en algún patrón de arquitectura concreto. Supongo que tendrá su historia, ¿alguien que arroje algo de luz al respecto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`src` siempre se entiende como *source* (fuente).

En el conjunto de carpetas de un proyecto el directorio `src` almacenaría el código fuente de dicho proyecto.

Según *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, el código fuente, o sea, el código que se almacena en el directorio `src` de un proyecto es:

> El código escrito por un programador en un lenguaje de alto nivel y
>   legible por personas pero no por computadoras. El código fuente se
>   debe convertir a código de objeto o lenguaje de máquina antes de que
>   una computadora pueda leer o ejecutar el programa.

La definición de *Collins English Dictionary* es muy parecida:

> Forma original de un programa de computadora antes de que se convierta
>   en un código legible por máquina.

Y según *Thesaurus (WordNet 3.0)*:

> Instrucciones del programa escritas como un archivo de texto ASCII;
>   debe ser traducido por un compilador o intérprete o ensamblador al
>   código objeto para una computadora en particular antes de la
>   ejecución.

- Ver fuente de estas tres definiciones en [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/source+code)

En definitiva, es el código que el programador escribe para que luego sea compilado.

---

En cuanto a su origen, no encontré nada al respecto. No obstante, el origen puede estar en Linux, el cual cuenta con un standard llamado [File System Hierarchy](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrsrcSourceCode), bastante documentado y mantenido por Linux Foundation.

Dentro de ese documento, vemos que Linux regula el uso de `src` entre otros muchos nombres que formarían parte de una convención de nombres que no tendría nada que envidiar a ninguna otra.

Por ejemplo en el apartado [6.1.9](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrsrcSourceCode2):

> #### 6.1.9. `/usr/src` : Source code
>
> For systems based on glibc, there are no specific guidelines for this
>   directory. For systems based on Linux libc revisions prior to glibc,
>   the following guidelines and rationale apply:
>
> The only source code that should be placed in a specific location is
>   the Linux kernel source code. It is located in `/usr/src/linux`.
>
> If a C or C++ compiler is installed, but the complete Linux kernel
>   source code is not installed, then the include files from the kernel
>   source code must be located in these directories:
>
> ```
> /usr/src/linux/include/asm-<arch>
> /usr/src/linux/include/linux `<arch>` is the name of the system architecture.
> ```
>
> Note
>
> `/usr/src/linux` may be a symbolic link to a kernel source code tree.
>
> Rationale
>
> It is important that the kernel include files be located in
>   `/usr/src/linux` and not in `/usr/include` so there are no problems
>   when system administrators upgrade their kernel version for the first
>   time.

Puede que este minucioso trato de Linux haya pasado a otros lenguajes y también a las estructuras de los proyectos en casi todos los lenguajes actuales.

`src` es usado también por ejemplo en HTML, para indicar la fuente (dirección URL) de una imagen.

Comment: Si que parece una cosa heredada de sistemas UNIX. Una de esas cosas que se hacen 'porque siempre se ha hecho así...' El caso es saber que no  tiene algún cometido específico o es un standart 'de facto' en otros entornos. Yo lo veo mucho en librerías PHP y la verdad que este lenguaje esta muy relacionado con Linux, conque por ahí deben de ir los tiros. Saludos.

Comment: @Orici los proyectos de Java (Netbeans, Eclipse...) también se crean así, lo mismo los de Android Studio, crean automáticamente una carpeta `src` donde se almacena el código fuente.